# Images not displaying on site or media library

Tags: uploads, media, media-library

I ran into a problem with my site which is basically a portfolio site. I show my works as galleries in different pages.
When I first uploaded my media, everything was fine and the site looked good. Unfortunately after a while I noticed that my images are gone.
I deactivated all of my plugins, even the necessary ones, checked the permission of gallery files on my host and all were set to 644 but the gallery shows empty squares. The site doesn't show even my logo, plus my font doesn't work either!

Please help me.

you can view my site here which has over 500 images on it, but doesn't show anything!
(http://decorsazanparvaz.ir/)

Comment: Have you checked via FTP or a file manager to see whether the files exist on your server? Perhaps you enabled a CDN at some point and that stopped working - it's likely that if you contact your host for support they can help determine what happened and how to fix it (and hopefully they also have backups if you don't).

Comment: URL like http://decorsazanparvaz.ir/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/home_interior_subheader_bg.jpg make error 500. maybe have you a strange .htaccess file in "wp-content/uploads" ?

Comment: @WebElaine  I checked files on server all media exists there. I found a .htaccess file in uploads folder where Kaperto said and deleted that. Fortunately most of images are showing now but not all of them. forexample, my background image for all pages. Is there anything else I should check?  Thank you both very much

Comment: @Kaperto Thank you for your help. I found that mysteriuos .htacccess file in uploads folder and I deleted that. Still some images are not shown. Any ideas?

Comment: Since there were less than 10 images missing, I uploaded them again. So, The site is working ok now. Thank you both very much

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Kaperto, I found a .htaccess file in uploads folder and deleted that. Fortunately after that most of my images were back and the site started to work again. 
The loss of my data was less than 10 images, so I uploaded them again. Everything's fine now.
Still don't know how the problem happened at the first place (mysterious .htaccess file in uploads folder)

Comment: If mysterious things are happening, I'd also poke around the site to look for files that shouldn't be there, and index.php/wp-config,php/wp-settings.php that have strange code in them.

Comment: I did that.but I believe it was because of one of my plugins. I'll make sure to use plugins wisely and only the necessary ones. Thank you @RickHellewell